# Converting only a date to combobox

Tags: c#, sql

Got one question:

I got this:

`public DateTime StartFrom;` //I store here for example this fromat of date:

2011-10-10 19:34:12

Now i retreive only an hour  (and it works fine):

```
TextBox.Text = Strings.Format(StartFrom, "HH:mm");
```

But now I want only a date I try, but I don;t know what's wrong in syntax?:

```
combobox.Value = Convert.ToString("NewObowiazujeOd", "short date"); //wrong ..
```

I want to this formt in combobox : yyy-mm-dd

Comment: `StartFrom.ToShortDateString()` exists

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
combobox.Value = StartFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this ...

```
 combobox.Value = StartFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

if you want to change all values in this format you can do like this..

```
 this.comboBox.FormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Comment: No, no I got already the answer is:
Convert.ToDateTime(StartFrom.ToShortDateString());

Comment: Why do you want it to convert a DateTime to a string and then back to a DateTime?